# Bluetooth adapter does not work

Tags: bluetooth, firmware

Wants to load firmware rtl8761bu_fw.bin but this was not installed.
Various instructions on the web for how to install this either led to the mentioned file not being available (e.g. https://mpow.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/mpow_MPBH456AB_driver+for+Linux.tgz) or not containing the firmware files.

Tried instructions at https://gist.github.com/rometsch/dfd24fb09c85c1ad2f25223dc1481aaa but without any success.

Any ideas for how to get this to work?

My system: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS  5.15.0-43-generic

Answer (score 1):

Please do:

```
wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_fw.bin
sudo mv rtl8761bu_fw.bin /usr/lib/firmware/rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_fw.bin
```

You should be all set.

Comment: `sudo` is needed to download there.

Comment: I have mentioned that I tried this and it did not work  in the gist i linked to (see https://gist.github.com/rometsch/dfd24fb09c85c1ad2f25223dc1481aaa). However, I did not reboot after all my attempts, so it may work.

Answer (score 0):

I did not always reboot with everything I tried (see https://gist.github.com/rometsch/dfd24fb09c85c1ad2f25223dc1481aaa) so I am not sure which steps exactly would be sufficient or not.

To help any others who encounter the same problem:

I eventually ended up following the steps mentioned in the zip file shared as part of this YouTube video: I downloaded https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FkzIOuNAc1HErqbhkmbkwEisviAQP2IC/view and compiled and installed as instructed. After this, the adapter worked.

What seems to be different there is that this process also creates /lib/modules/5.15.0-43-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/rtk_btusb.ko (anyone knows if this is needed and why?)

So the procedure suggested by chili555 may work or you may need to go through the steps above but eventually it ended up working!

Comment: You suggest to download some unknown file form a Google Drive.

Comment: Thank you, this instruction is work!

Comment: @Pilot6 - I am sharing what worked for me but I agree that this could be a security threat. If you find a better source which is more trustworthy, please share it here.